# I just write a wrapcommand in java but sometimes it do not print the command output. WHY

Tags: java, shell, process, runtime.exec

I just write a simple commandwrapper in java, this is construction function:

```
Process process;
Thread in;
Thread out; 

public CommandWrapper(Process process) {
    this.process = process;
    final InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    // final BufferedReader
    //final BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    out = new Thread() {
        // String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int count = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println(lineNumber + ":"
                            + new String(buffer, 0, count - 1));
                    // line=r.readLine();
                    // System.out.println(lineNumber+":"+line);
                    lineNumber++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    final OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
    in = new Thread() {
        String line;

        public void run() {
            try {
                //while (true) {
                    outputStream.write((reader.readLine() + "/n")
                            .getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();
                //}
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
}

public void startIn() {
    in.start();
}
```

This is when it invoke:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        CommandWrapper command = new CommandWrapper(Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("wget www.google.com"));
        //command.startIn();
        command.startOut();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It works OK when I run simple command like ls -l or other local commander, but when I want to run wget command it is print out nothing as output. I do know why.

Comment: Never have an empty try-catch block. At the very least print out the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: As is common when using the `exec()` command, the above is a very fragile and poorly written example.  Be sure to go through (and implement) the tips of the Java World article linked from the [`exec` tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & the failure reason will probably become more clear.

Comment: I do try-catch at invoke part, do you read the last part of my code?

Comment: I believe your comment was to @DiegoBasch (good catch, BTW).  While one of the three try/catch statements dumps the stack trace, ***every*** try/catch should do so.  Further tips beyond my first comment.  1) Use a `ProcessBuilder` to make the `Process`.  Break the `String command` (e.g. `"wget www.google.com"`) into `String[] commands`.

Comment: @user504909 your `run()` methods in `CommandWrapper` don't. Never means **never**.

Comment: @Diego Basch Thank you. I got it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :) You should write up an answer & accept it.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you've shown and your description of how you use it, the best guess is that *an exception occurs, and you silently swallow it*. This happens whenever you have an empty `catch`-block, like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

You happen to have one in the `run()` method of your `out` thread.

### Silently swallowing exceptions is extremely bad practice.

You should ***never ever ever*** do this! Depending on your application the appropriate solution varies, but since you're writing a console application you probably want to print the stack trace of the exception. In Java, this is done with `e.printStackTrace()`:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another option (which might not be appropriate in this specific case) is to *rethrow* the exception, possibly after *wrapping* it in another exception (for example one you've written specifically for your application):

```
catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
// or
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MyOwnException(e);
}
```

Doing either of these two (printing stack trace or rethrowing) will ensure that no exceptions go unnoticed.

#### However, no rule without exceptions ;)

There are cases when it is appropriate to have empty `catch`-clauses. If you know that some operation might throw an exception and you just want to proceed when it happens, an empty `catch`-clause is a good way to do it. However, the cases where this is appropriated are limited to (at least) the following conditions:

1. **You must know the specific type of the exception.** You *never* want to catch a *general exception* (i.e. `catch (Exception e)` since that might be thrown for any reason which you cannot possibly predict. If you use empty `catch` clauses, *always catch specific exception type (such as `IOException`)*.
2. **You must know why the exception was thrown.** You should only swallow exceptions that you know the origin of. If you swallow any other exceptions, you'll end up like in this situation, where your code doesn't do what you expect and you can't understand why. Swallowed exceptions are extremely difficult to debug, since they are, well, swallowed, and thereby hidden.
3. **You must know that you don't care about the exception.** The reason to use empty `catch`-clauses is mainly (read: *only*) to handle situations where the code you're using treats something as exceptional, while you do not. By *exeptional* in this context we mean "something that shouldn't really happen, and if it does, something is seriously wrong."

**An example of when empty `catch`-clauses are appropriate:**
Say that you are using someone elses code that opens a file for reading, given the absolute path of the file. Most such routines throw exceptions if the file does not exist - it is the job of the client code (i.e. the code that calls the "open file routine") to ensure that the file exists before trying to open it. Exceptions will also be thrown if, for example, the user running the program does not have permissions to read the file.

Now, you might not really care *why* the file couldn't be opened, but if it couldn't you just want to keep going - in that case, you swallow all exceptions related to reading the file (in Java, likely an `IOException` of some sort). *Note that you do **not** swallow all exceptions - only the ones related to opening the file!*

Comment: Also, credit is due to [Diego Basch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/586880/diego-basch) for commenting about emtpy  catch -clauses and inspiring me to write up this answer.